# Exposed C++ functions with SWIG to Go: Shared library not found

Tags: shared-libraries, go, swig

I am using SWIG to expose some C++ functions to Go with following commands:

```
gcc -std=c++0x -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -fPIC -shared -L./lib -lsomething -o example.so
swig -go -intgosize 32 example.i
go tool 6g example.go
go tool 6c -I /usr/lib/go/pkg/linux_amd64 -D_64BIT example_gc.c
go tool pack grc example.a example.6 example_gc.6
rm -f example_wrap.c

go install  // this installs the generated .a; not the .so
```

For my project, I am using a /src:/pkg:/bin file structure, with $GOHOME pointing to it. When I use `import "example"`  in another Go package I get:

```
error while loading shared libraries: example.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Where do I have to put the shared library, so that it will be found? Without messing around in system directories.

Comment: From your output it looks like no object file is defined.  Would you be able to link the example.go unit?  Also check to make sure when doing the import "C" in go the line above it declares your linker flags, like so:

// #cgo LDFLAGS: -Lbin -lv8wrap -lstdc++

Also make sure you're setting the library path when running the other package. ex: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$GOHOME/bin otherpackage

Comment: I am using SWIG, there is no `import "C"` or cgo line. I can link the .go. I set the LD_LIBRARY_PATH and now the shared library is found! Unfortunately I now get `undefined symbol: _wrap_example_function`.